# UISearchDisplayController no longer hides the full UITableView below it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Trying to overhaul an app to iOS7, I encountered that the `UISearchDisplayController` plugged in a `UITableViewController` behavior has changed.
It will no longer hide the full `UITableView` that contains all the data below it.
Instead, it will strangely overlap it with the **results** or the '**no results**' message, showing the cells with the data that should not be shown but without the ability to move/scroll it (only the results, if any).

what gives?

Answer (score 0):

UISearchDisplayController is a bit broken in iOS7, especially on the iPad.  Pete Steinberger has a blog post on [fixing UISearchDisplayController](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/fixing-uisearchdisplaycontroller-on-ios-7/) that might help.